iframe video to cover a div no matter its ration
I'm currently developing a portfolio website type with Kirby cms, loading content dynamically.
My issue is, my slides are split depending on the number of children of the folder, however I would like my embed video (from vimeo) to always cover my entire div wether its 100% of the screen width or 50%, 25% etc. of the screen same thing with window resize or so, any how, just like an img object-fit: cover would. I know it's possible with not embed video / background video but in that case I cant seem to make it work.
Is that possible?
My HTML looks like:

        <?php if ($section->vimeo()->isNotEmpty()): ?>
            <div class="slide-projets">
                <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/<?= $section->vimeo()?>?background=1&amp;" style="width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

and my CSS:
.slide-projets {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-projets iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1; 
}


A possible solution is not to use Styles for your iframe width/height.
Try setting the iframe to have an Element's width/height (as an alternative to Style's width/height)
<div class="slide-projets" style="height:100vh">

<iframe width="100%" height="100%" 
src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/173487055" 
frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="">
</iframe>

